# Is there any way to add multiple users to youtube private video at once?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, youtube, youtube-data-api

We are developing LMS for college students, For that we need to add multiple users into one youtube video at once. Our requirement is to add the youtube video as private. Then we add all user emails to add users into the video. Also, if new user joins we have to add them into previous private videos in our channel. Is there any possibility to achieve this requirement using you tube data API or any other possible way?

Tried using you tube data API.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I suggest taking a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and reading [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). We're here to help as soon as you can show us what code you've written so far, so don't forget to include a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)!